# Can't figure out why perl prints out newline and then data instead of vice versa

Tags: perl, stdout

Well, my code is pretty simple. It should print content + \n but the result is somehow reversed.

Here the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 

use strict;

my $founds; 

while (<>){ 
    $$founds{$2} = $& while  m/([A-Z]{3})([a-z])([A-Z] {3})/g;                               
}

print sort keys %$founds, "\n";
```

And the result is:

```
(here is a newline)  
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Hope it happens also with your configurations (if you want to download the file I used on my code [go here](http://pastebin.com/J6pY2CMx))

Anyway, do you know something about it?

P.S: the regex doesn't allow newline characters, so it's unlikely the problem belongs from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you get the newline first is that you include it in the sort due to lack of parentheses. Do this instead:

```
print sort(keys %{$founds}), "\n";
```

The newline comes first by coincidence (or rather, by virtue of being a whitespace character amongst non-whitespace).

For clarification:

```
my %found = ( foo => 1, bar => 1 );   # keys returns "foo", "bar"
print sort keys %found, "\n";         # sort gets "foo", "bar", "\n"
         # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------- arguments to sort()
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes Perl is so unpredictable!

Comment: @none Not at all. Perl is 100% predictable. It would have been unpredictable for Perl to not include the newline in the sort. `sort()` is no different from any other subroutine that takes a list as argument: If you give it a list, it takes that list. It is the very essence of clarity.

Comment: Pretend you had used `print sort "a","b","c","\n"` instead. How is `sort` suppose to know the `"\n"` is supposed to be passed to `print` instead of `sort`? Same in your code.

Comment: @none try say instead of print to avoid things like this

Comment: @TLP, of course. I'd just have to pay more attention when using parenthesis in function calling.

Answer (score -2):

there is a newline on the end of every input line in perl. you need to do `chomp` as the first thing in your while loop

```
use strict;

my $founds; 

while (<>){ 
   chomp;
   $founds->{$2} = $& while  m/([A-Z]{3})([a-z])([A-Z] {3})/g;                               
}

print sort keys %{$founds}, "\n";
```

you should also use the -> notation to access a reference and I would enclose the % dereference in braces to aid legibility